# How to Detect color from the image object

Tags: c#

Hello I want to detect the color of car in image
Following Steps I've done 
I have detected the car in image,
    i have created  the bins of colors for example ranging the  value 0-25 will be equal to  0  and have ten bins for each part of color of `RGB` so could you have any algorithm to get the color of `car/object`.

Comment: Get a bunch of pixels and average the values?

Answer (score 0):

[Euclidean distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance).

[This article on The CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17044/Find-the-Nearest-Color-with-C-Using-the-Euclidean) uses it to find a websafe color closest to a user-picked color.